# how can I add custom function at login page

Tags: customization

I want to add one custom function in login-page of Ubuntu or other linux flavors.
So far now I have tried to modify grub but did not helped then I tried to search for the config file of Login page but couldn't find.

Comment: Hi, what you want to edit? What this function should do? Please give an example.

Comment: I want to add 2 factor authentication field.

Comment: Can we assume that you already have enabled 2FA for your display manager? Which is it [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) or some other? Please check [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/208205/how-to-use-two-factor-authentication-on-your-linux-desktop-with-google-authenticator/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Lightdm Gtk Greeter Settings** to edit your *Ubuntu login screen*. To use it execute in the terminal:

```
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings-pkexec
```

If you want to edit your *grub menu* you can use the **Grub Customizer**
In the terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer
```